# Cucumber Feature plugin giving "Step 'xxxxx' does not have a matching glue code"

Tags: automation, cucumber, feature-file

[image]I am  developing a framework in cucumber. I have setup everything right from folder structure to maven and integration with Testng.
But there is small warning that eating me from inside is even though my project runs and executes fine . My feature file shows warning "Step 'xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx' does not have a matching glue code" for every step that I have written in the feature file.  Please someone suggest me what needs to be done here

Comment: nobody is facing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of Cucumber you are using, your IDE and the version of the plugin you are using, you may get this warning. You could try upgrading your plugin to see if that helps. (Or upvoting/logging an issue with the plugin for support of the Cucumber version you are using)